# Is it possible to consider the set of orbits of a continuous dynamical system on a compact metric space as a topological space?

Tags: abstract-algebra, dynamical-systems, topological-groups, semigroups

I am studying algebraic properties of a set of all orbits of a continuous dynamical system on a compact metric space.

I consider a binary operation defined on orbits that yields certain algebraic structure on this set (monoid, semigroup, etc.).

How can I define a topology on the set of orbits in order for the algebraic and topological structures to agree with each other?

Comment: The usual approach (when no algebraic structure is being discussed) is to pick "being in the same orbit" as an equivalence relation for two points of manifold and then take a quotient of an appropriate subset using it. For example, if you pick a linear diffeomorphism $\overline{x} = 2x, \; \overline{y} = 2y$, cut out an origin and construct a quotient space, then each orbit can be uniquely represented as a point in the annulus $1 \leqslant x^2 + y^2 \leqslant 4$ where point $(\cos\phi, \sin\phi)$ and $(2 \cos\phi, 2 \sin\phi)$ are glued; hence orbit space is a torus. Does it work for you?

Comment: @Evgeny, I think it does work for me.  To define a topology on the quotient space, I can define open sets to be equivalence classes whose union is open in the base space.